# Test a ruby gem binary

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am developing a ruby gem which will have a binary.

I am trying to develop the binary but i am worried its not finding my requires because the gem isnt installed as a gem is there a way to test the binary without packaging it as a gem?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "middleman_ember_scaffold/load_paths"

# Start the CLI
MiddlemanEmberScaffold::Cli::Base.start
```

sits in a file named mse and ive added my bin folder of gem to path

```
.
└── middleman_ember_scaffold
    ├── Gemfile
    ├── LICENSE.txt
    ├── README.md
    ├── Rakefile
    ├── bin
    │   └── mes
    ├── lib
    │   ├── middleman_ember_scaffold
    │   │   ├── cli.rb
    │   │   ├── load_paths.rb
    │   │   └── version.rb
    │   └── middleman_ember_scaffold.rb
    └── middleman_ember_scaffold.gemspec

4 directories, 10 files
```

when i run mes i get

```
/Users/justin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- middleman_ember_scaffold/load_paths (LoadError)
    from /Users/justin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/justin/middleman-generator/middleman_ember_scaffold/bin/mes:7:in `<main>'
```

i'd like to be able to run and develop mes without re-packaging everytime i make a change.

Comment: Can you provide some more information, like why you think your required files aren't being found? How are you trying to execute it? Just a note: it's really easy to package a gem just on your system and play around with it. You don't have to publish it, and can learn a lot that way.

Comment: yeah i mean i know how to package gems.

Comment: updated with more details. i should know better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use RUBYLIB Environment Variable

The problem you're facing is that your source directory isn't getting some of magic applied to installed gems, and therefore doesn't have your lib directory in the $LOAD_PATH. While there are other ways to deal with this, for testing I'd recommend just adding your lib directory to the RUBYLIB environment variable. For example:

```
RUBYLIB="/path/to/middleman_ember_scaffold/lib:$RUBYLIB"
export RUBYLIB
bin/mes
```

should work for any Bourne-compatible shell. If you're running Bash, and don't have anything else stored in RUBYLIB, you might even be able to shorten the invocation to:

```
RUBYLIB="/path/to/middleman_ember_scaffold/lib" bin/mes
```

Either way, once Ruby knows what directories it should add to the $LOAD_PATH everything should work just fine.

Comment: this is the conclusion i was coming to reading some other info thanks!

Comment: alias mes='RUBYLIB="/Users/justin/middleman-generator/middleman_ember_scaffold/lib" mes' works well too

Answer (score 19):

Probably a "better" way would be to do the following:

```
$ ruby -I./lib bin/mes
```

It does the same as changing your load path, but it only does it for the command you're executing.

Comment: as long as i dont export RUBYLIB it has the same effect but thanks for the additional info.